# How to import key created by near-cli into NEAR Wallet?

Tags: nearprotocol

I've generated my NEAR account key using `near generate-key` command. I have `.json` file with the key. How do I import it into NEAR Wallet (https://wallet.near.org)?

Answer (score 5):

See docs at https://docs.near.org/docs/tools/near-cli#4b-near-generate-key-accountid---seedphraseyour-seed-phrase

1. Generate a new seed phrase (e.g. by trying to create an account here https://wallet.testnet.near.org but not following through).

   Any way of generating random seed phrase / password with enough entropy works (e.g. you can use `pwgen 64` on Mac).

   Make sure it's 12 words on one line separated by spaces, such as `other awake horn height much pipe radio scene cabbage mountain visual captain`. You can use a [BIP39 phrase generator](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=BIP39%20phrase%20generator&t=brave&ia=web) online since [NEAR protocol uses BIP39 seed phrases](https://github.com/near/near-seed-phrase).
2. Generate a public key from that seed phrase by running:

   `near generate-key example-acct.near --seedPhrase "<your seed phrase>"`

   This will produce a response like:

   > Key pair with ed25519:GkMNfc92fwM1AmwH1MTjF4b7UZuceamsq96XPkHsQ9vi public key for an account "example-acct.near"
3. Associate that public key with your account by running:

   `NEAR_ENV=mainnet near add-key <your-account-id> <public-key-from-last-step>`
4. Visit https://wallet.near.org/recover-seed-phrase and paste the seed phrase you generated in Step 1. This will log you into that account.

> A product manager for NEAR Wallet confirmed on 2022-01-13 that the **Wallet does not support subaccounts**. So the above steps likely will not work for a subaccount.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, which got me started. I edited the answer to clean up the steps since I had a little bit of trouble initially and hope that these instructions are now clearer.