# Recover seed-phrase from private key

Tags: nearprotocol, near

I've created an account using near-cli / near-sdk, thus got private keys in `~/.near-credentials`.

In order to use the new account in [wallet.near.org](https://wallet.near.org) I need the seed-phrase. How I can "convert" a private key to a seed-phrase?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64598374/470749 might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is cryptographically impossible, assuming that this works in NEAR the same as in Bitcoin etc.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/62530/48808 says something similar, for those who are interested.